# What's is the difference between the following sentences:

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

What's is the difference between the following sentences:

1.if I wanted to leave, I would leave now.

2.If I had wanted to leave, I would have left by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meanings are basically the same in your two examples.

The slight nuance might be

> **1.if I wanted to leave, I would leave now.**

means you are talking about considering leaving *right now*, whereas

> **2.If I had wanted to leave, I would have left by now.**

means you were considering a some point before.